# How to get event by event id into fullcalendar 4.0

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using fullcalendar 4.0, and trying to get event source record with both the methods and 10411 is the "id" filed valuse in event as:

```
{id : 10411,title : 'sample',start : 'date'}

var eventdetails = calendar.getEventSourceById('10411');
var eventdetails = calendar.getEventSourceById('clientEvents','10411');
```

Please share any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

What you appear to have there is a single event, not an event source. (An event source, as the name suggests, defines a **source** of events, i.e. a place to fetch events from, not an individual event.)

There are different methods for fetching individual events - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEventById and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents

So in your case you would write

```
var eventdetails =  calendar.getEventById(10411);
```

Comment: Thank you @ADyson, for more details please check the link https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3, We can not get event with any other field except ID,once we get all events with getEVents method,  to filter the events use  var someEvents = calendar.getEvents().filter(function(event) {
  return event.title === 'My Event';
});

Comment: In v4 you can just get all the events with the `calendar.getEvents()` method, and then filter them yourself - filtering an array with JavaScript is quite easy, you will find lots of examples online.